# Xamarin Forms ScrollView issue with Editor when using the software Keyboard

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, editor, scrollview

I'm using Xamarin Forms with iOS. I have an Editor within a scrollview. The editor is set to the fill most of the page. This is working.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
        <Editor x:Name="NotesEditor" Text="{Binding Contact.AttendanceDetails.Notes, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" TextChanged="NotesEditor_TextChanged"  ></Editor>
        <Label x:Name="RemainingText" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="40"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The issue is when the software keyboard is used, the page scrolls and when the user starts typing, they do not initially see the text they are typing on the keyboard without manual scrolling.

Is there a way the software keyboard doesn't push the scrollview? So the user can do it manually maybe?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Managed a fix by adding an event to the Editor Focused event:

XAML:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="scrollview">
    <StackLayout>
        <Editor x:Name="NotesEditor" Text="{Binding Contact.Notes, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" TextChanged="NotesEditor_TextChanged" Focused="NotesEditor_Focused"   ></Editor>
        <Label x:Name="RemainingText" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="40"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Code behind:

```
private void NotesEditor_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        scrollview.ScrollToAsync(0, 0,true);
    }
```

Comment: What happens though if you want to focus the cursor on a location outside of visibility of `0,0`? I'm facing the same problem, but the user may want to start editing at the bottom of the page for example, which requires scrolling to see.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your use case but why not completely remove the ScrollView ? There's no reason to scroll if the editor is full screen, You can apply margin to the label if you still want to see it.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Editor x:Name="NotesEditor" Text="{Binding Contact.AttendanceDetails.Notes, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" TextChanged="NotesEditor_TextChanged"  ></Editor>
        <Label x:Name="RemainingText" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" margin="10, 30, 10, 30"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: well he needs the scrollview so the Editor slides with the keybored when it shows and not disappears.

Comment: i need the scroll-view as if there is a load of text that even goes past the screen etc, there is no way of the control scrolling unfortunately. I've managed a fix, i'll put the answer as well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this component it might work  with no need for the scrollView . However it will fail if you enabled the expanding of the editor .

https://devlinduldulao.pro/how-to-fix-keyboard-overlapping-or-covering-entry/

Answer (score 0):

If you want an editor in a scrollview, you can try this solution.

```
<ContentPage>
 <ScrollView >
                  <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                     
                   <Editor VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                                       AutoSize="TextChanges"
                              -----
                              Grid.Row="0" />
                     </Grid>
  </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

for eg: your code should be like this

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
   <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                 <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Editor x:Name="NotesEditor" Text="{Binding Contact.AttendanceDetails.Notes, Mode=TwoWay}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" TextChanged="NotesEditor_TextChanged" Grid.Row="0" ></Editor>
        <Label x:Name="RemainingText" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="40" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Note: You can Set hightRequest for the Scroll view if required.